# Dynamic type conversion using Type class

Tags: c#, types, casting, json.net

I have the following class:

```
public class DataItemWrapper
{
    public Type DataType { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

Assume I have a method 'SaveToDb' which saves the `DataItemWrapper` object into Sqlite db with the following conversions:

1. `Type DataType` saved as string (DataType.AssemblyQualifiedName)
2. `object Data` is being serialized as a json and saved as a string.

Now I need to write a method `GetFromDb` which query the "DataItemWrappers" table and gets as an input `Type DataType` and a string in a json format which represent the object I saved before.

Inside `GetFromDb` method, I need to deserialize dataJson into `DataType` type.

I dont want to deserialize it into an object type but to a more concrete one.
for example if i'm sending for save the next object: `new DataItemWrapper{DataType = typeof(Cat), Data = new Cat()};`
I would like to deserialize `DataItemWrapper.Data` json into a `Cat`type and not to an `Object` one.

This is the json deserialization syntax:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<some type here>(rdr["Data"].ToString());
```

I need to do something like:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<cast to Cat type using DataType parameter>(rdr["Data"].ToString());
```

How can I do it?

Hope that I was clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several [overloads](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) of the `DeserializeObject` method. One of them is:

```
public static Object DeserializeObject(
    string value,
    Type type
)
```

So you can just write:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
    rdr["Data"].ToString(),
    Type.GetType(rdr["DataType"].ToString())
);
```

You wan use a different approach to retrieve the type, like `yourAssembly.GetType`, I don't know which one will work best for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Since the type is available for you, you can do the following:

```
var mytype = GetTypeFromName(rdr["Type"]);
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rdr["Data"].ToString(), mytype);
```

Here is the [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm) for that `DeserializeObject` overload.